# Updating a Card in a CardScrollAdapter from an AsyncTask

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I've implemented a `CardScrollAdapter` to show a list of `Cards` in Google Glass. Each card has text and an image. I want the image to come from a content provider (specifically, `MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails`) so it must be loaded in an `AsyncTask`.

How can I modify the view returned from the adapter's `getView` method from the `AsyncTask`, where the view is obtained from a `Card`?

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_row, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    mVideoColumnIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
    mIdColumnIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);

    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);

    Card card = new Card(mContext);
    card.setImageLayout(ImageLayout.FULL);
    card.setText(mCursor.getString(mVideoColumnIndex));
    card.setFootnote((String.format("%d of %d", mCursor.getPosition() + 1, mCursor.getCount())));


    long id = mCursor.getLong(mIdColumnIndex);

            // AsyncTask not included for brevity (since it doesn't work yet)
    new ImageLoader().execute(card, Long.valueOf(id));

    return card.getView();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your owns layouts. If you use `Card`, you can't modify the image after calling `getView()`

If you don't know how to do a similar layout of `Card`, Google give you some examples here: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui-widgets#xml_layouts

PD: I think that you could change the image if you could know the id of the imageView that is created when `card.getView()` is called and i think you can do this while you are debuging and cheking the variables.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was a way to leverage the `Card` class without having to replicate its nuances but I'm afraid you're right. The image in a `Card` is not displayed in an `ImageView`, but rather a Glass specific widget, so we can't use it in our code just yet.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Card/CardBuilder with an embedded custom layout. That way you can call and grab the ImageView.

```
View view = new CardBuilder(context, CardBuilder.Layout.EMBED_INSIDE)
    .setEmbeddedLayout(R.layout.my_view)
    .setFootnote("Your Images")
    .setTimestamp("today")
    .getView();
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_view_1);
imgView....;
```

That should work for you if you want to use the CardBuilder.

Comment: Please vote this up for others to know that this code exists.